# Взаимодействие с datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет, пишу свою программу и возник такой вопрос.
У меня есть Datagridview которая заполняется при нажатии на элемент меню названиями таблиц с помощью Sql запроса из базы данных вот код:

```
private void Material_10x11ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection SQLconnectionAccount = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MPM.Properties.Settings.AccountConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SQLconnectionAccount.Open();

    var AccountView = new SqlDataAdapter($"SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%Material_10x11%'", SQLconnectionAccount);
    var dtbl = new DataTable();
    AccountView.Fill(dtbl);
    dataGridView.DataSource = dtbl;

    SQLconnectionAccount.Close();

}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на имя таблицы она открывалась в DatagridView вместо имен таблиц, заранее извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, всем спасибо!

Comment: Ничего не понятно, что нужно, этот код работает?